# How to include the assembly(DLL) in the project when I dynamically select the assembly (DLL) in dynamic WPF Project?

Tags: c#

I have to do a task in Visual Studio

1. I have the VSIX Project with the Project Template
2. I have the Context Menu (Jose) in the Project Node (Project Node>Right Click > (Jose)Below to Context Menu(Add))
3. If I run the VSIX project then New Instance Occurs
4. In that Instance I Create the Project using my Own Project template
5. After Creating , (Select the Project Node in Solution Explorer > right click > then my Context Menu(Jose) appears in that dialog box below to (Add))
6. If i click the (Jose) Context Menu then Sub Menu (Add New Item ) Appears.
7. If I click the Add New Item Sub Menu then WPF Form Dialog box.
8. Dialog Box contains 10 Check Box with 10 assembly(DLL) content like(system. Data)
9. I want if I select any Check Box(DLL Assembly) and Click the Add Button then That selected CheckBox(DLL assembly) need to add(include) to the current project . After Added the assembly(DLL) then It displayed in the Project Node below the (assemblies)

This is my Requirement (step 9) . Give the Solution to this

I Expect to include the assembly to the Project Application

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the actual issue. It sounds like you are talking about *project references*. But I have no idea what "dynamic WPF project" even means, and "dialog"/"context menu" is really unclear unless you specify *what* dialog/context menu you are using.

Comment: Yes , It's  like Project Reference . My Question is How to include the Reference to the Project Application dynamically (Using Coding ).Kindly give any solution

Comment: You need to describe what the actual goal is. There are solutions for dynamically loading things like plugins, but you should describe the actual goal in order to prevent X/Y-problems.

Comment: My actual goal is I have to add reference like (.dll file) in the application by own with own reference manager in Visual Studio . I have created my own reference manager. My need is How to include the (.dll file) in the application?